# Form in right panel is not updating when a menuitem is clicked on the left panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have added splitcontainer in a form for my application. Basically, I have multiple buttons in left panel, each having drop down menu items added dynamically. When an item is clicked, it brings a common form with updated values(in labels) in right panel. It works fine for the first time when a menu item is clicked.But in the next click of another menu item,  brings out the old form details which should be giving a form with updated label values.The issue I am having is that the form is not updating label values. I couldn't find much about this issue online.Any help would be much appreciated.

Splitcontainer form;

```
public int lightIndex
{
    get { return _lightindex; }
    set { _lightindex = value; }
}

public int groupIndex
{
    get { return _groupindex; }
    set { _groupindex = value; }
}
```

Button click event

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnSender = (Button)sender;
    groupIndex = groupbuttons.IndexOf((Button)sender);
    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    List<UserLight> alllight = Global.g_userlightgroups[_groupindex].getUserlights();

    for (int i = 0; i < alllight.Count(); i++)
    {
        ContextMenu = cm;
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem(alllight[i].getlightType().ToString());
        item.Click += Item_Click;
        cm.MenuItems.Add(item);
    }

    Point ptLowerLeft = new Point(0, btnSender.Height);
    ptLowerLeft = btnSender.PointToScreen(ptLowerLeft);
    cm.Show(btnSender, ptLowerLeft);
}

private void Item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    String lighttype = menuItem.Text;

    if (lighttype.Equals("PRIMITIVE"))
    {
        PrimitiveLight prim = new PrimitiveLight();
        prim.TopLevel = false;
        prim.Parent = lightcontainer.Panel2;

        prim.groupIndex = _groupindex;
        prim.lightIndex = menuItem.Index;
        prim.Show();
        prim.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
}
```

PrimitiveLight form: This form will be inserted into splitcontainer panel2 when menu item is clicked.

```
private int _lightindex;
private int _groupindex;

public int lightIndex
{
    get { return _lightindex; }
    set { _lightindex = value; }
}
public int groupIndex
{
    get { return _groupindex; }
    set { _groupindex = value; }
}

private void PrimitiveLight_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lightDefname.Text = Global.g_userlightgroups[_groupindex].getUserlights().ElementAt(_lightindex).getdefName().ToString();
    lightCustname.Text = Global.g_userlightgroups[_groupindex].getUserlights().ElementAt(_lightindex).getcustName().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Your code is long and unreadable. Your variable names are confusing. What is prim, lightcontainer, g_userlightgroups, getUserlights etc... In about a week it would be difficult for even you to understand it.

Comment: .I have solved the issue.These are the variables I use in my project. Next time, I'll use simple variables for posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

panel2.Refresh()  Maybe, dont know your issue but you can refresh the panel.

Comment: Able to resolve it by clearing the controls on panel2.Thanks for your input.